# Is socket.io asynchronous - do I need to lock global arrays/variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Will one socket.io callback (from a client) interrupt another function that is currently executing?

For example - a function that processes an array, and the array contents could change as the result of another client:

```
socket.on('user_joined', function(uid) {
    users.push(uid);
});

socket.on('user_left', function(uid) {
    users.splice(users.indexOf(uid), 1);
});

socket.on('a_random_function', function() {
    for (uid in users) {
        do something with users[uid]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is socket.io asynchronous

**Yes**, all NodeJS I/O is (or should be) asynchronous.

> Do I need to lock global arrays/variables?

**No**, only one thread is executing your Javascript at any one time. There is in fact no "lock" concept available that is equivalent to what you are imagining.

Perhaps you will find [NodeJS Event Loop Fundamendals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30553755/476716) and its answers helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Will one socket.io callback (from a client) interrupt another function that is currently executing?

No.

A function will never be interrupted by an event.

The event loop will check the queue of event triggered functions to run only after it is finished whatever it is currently doing.