# Conflict concerns in 2-player game in Nodejs Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to make a multiplayer game using socket.io in Nodejs. The game is for 2 players. It has a system as you see below. When the socket find-match event occurs, we add the waiting users to the list. If there is a user, we remove them from the list. Here is the code:

Client Code:

```js
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
    <button id="match-btn" onclick="match()">Find Match</button>
    <script>

        const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");

        function match() {
            socket.emit("find-match")
        }

    <script>
```

Server Code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const server = require('http').Server(app);
server.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port : 5000")
});
 const io = socketIo(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        credentials: true
    }
});

let waitPlayers = [];
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("connected");
    
      //code
      socket.on("find-match", (data) => {
        console.log(socket.id)
         
        // the user is already in the list
        if (waitPlayers.find(e => e.id == socket.id)) {
            console.log("user already exists") 
            return;
        }
        
        // If there is someone to match
        if (waitPlayers.length > 0) {
            const player = waitPlayers[0];
            // delete and match first pending user
            waitPlayers.pop();
            console.log(waitPlayers);

            //random key
            const roomkey = Math.random() * 10
            console.log(roomkey)
            player.join(roomkey);
            socket.join(roomkey);

            //send a message to others in the room
            io.to(roomkey).emit('start-match', "");


        } else {
            // add waitPlayers
            waitPlayers.push(socket);
            socket.emit("wait-match", "");
        }

    })

})
```

I don't know if I followed the right method. My concern is that if too many users use the project, could there be conflicts in the waitPlayers list? If yes, what should I do?

Comment: I don't see conflict potential. Cause your game is designed for exactly two players the ```waitPlayers``` list should only contain one player at max. You could replace it with a simple non-list variable. Socket.io is not multi-threaded so it will not process two request in parallel.

Comment: @flappix If 10 people press the button at the same time, wouldn't it be a problem for all of them to send requests? I'm worried if it will be a problem if everyone wants to match

Comment: Node.js is single threaded so it will process the 10 requests sequentially. Look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003741/is-socket-io-asynchronous-do-i-need-to-lock-global-arrays-variables or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185519/can-this-code-cause-a-race-condition-in-socket-io